# How to get IP address with jmdns lib on Android

Tags: android, bonjour

I use below code to get bonjour service:

```
try {
    jmdns = JmDNS.create();
    ddServiceListener(type, listener = new ServiceListener() {
        public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent ev) {
            System.out.println("Service resolved: "
            + ev.getInfo().getQualifiedName()
        + " port:" + ev.getInfo().getPort());
        }
        public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent ev) {
        }
    public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
        jmdns.requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName(), 1);
    }
    });
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It can find the device, but I don't now how to get their ip address.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please tell me , How did you get hostname, so that you can use it with `InetAddress.getByName(hostName) `??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you find **Hostname** and **Port**? If it is,then try to resolve the **Hostname** to an **IP address** with [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html).
If `InetAddress.getByName(hostName)` don't work, then try with `InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName)`.